# Not able to get DISTINCT column values :

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am working in Yii and, I have a table named : visits

It has two foreign keys : from_user_id and to_user_id which are linked to the 'user' table. 
Now the table visits has many same 'from_user_id' and I want to get retrieve them in Yii as DISCTINCT.

This is my code :

```
$visited = Visit::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('to_user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->distinct = true;

foreach($visited as $visits){

    echo User::model()->findByPk($visits->from_user_id,$criteria)->getFullName($visits->from_user_id);

   echo " <br>";
}
```

However, I am not able to get them as distinct.

This is my output :

```
san
san
san
Leo
Leo
```

I want the output as :

```
San
Leo
```

This is not getting me distinct values. Where am I going wrong??

Comment: But what other columns are being returned ?  `print_r($visits)` in the loop. Just because the value of `from_user_id` isn't distinct alone in that query doesn't mean it is not part of a larger distinct dataset.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the Yii framework to know what the method is for retrieving _only_ one column in a query.

Comment: MichaelBerkowski is correct, you need to tell Yii to select only the `from_user_id` column. This is done by `$criteria->select = 'from_user_id';` 2. Since you have foreign keys, you should also have corresponding relations. Tell Yii to eager load the relation that corresponds to the `from_user_id` foreign key, and get all your data in one query instead of N+1.

Comment: Thank you @DCoder!! I was missing the 'select' criteria only.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't be able to test it, but apart from possible minor syntax adjustment, this should help you:

```
$visited = Visit::model()->findAllByAttributes(
    array('to_user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id),
    array('distinct' => True)
);
```

According to the doc, [`findAllByAttribute`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#findAllByAttributes-detail) accept a *condition or criteria* parameter as second argument.

If this is an array (according the doc for [`find()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#find-detail)), it will serve to initialize the various [criteria properties](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#properties) of the requests.

Comment: That still does a `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM visits WHERE to_user_id = :to_user_id`.

Comment: @DCoder : Exactly! And Thanks to you , I was able to do it... It was missing :) Thank you!!